# How to parse a href with img

Tags: java, html, parsing

```
 <a href="$handler$&landing_url=https://foo.com/index.html">
  <img src="https://foo.com/images/08_180x80.gif" border="0" alt="">
</a>
```

I have this code which I need to return to calling service. However, while returning, i need to replace $handler$ with something i get from props file. Which is easy.

hard part is :

I need to get the landing_url , encrypt it, also add more info to it.

How can i parse this fragment into pieces ?

or is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regex you need: `/<a href=\".*?landing_url=(.*?)\">/`.

Putting all the code together:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "<a href=\"$handler$&landing_url=https://foo.com/index.html\">";
    String regex = "<a href=\".*?landing_url=(.*?)\">";
    List<String> parts = evaluate(regex, str);
    System.out.println("landing_url: " + parts.get(0));
}

public static List<String> evaluate(String regex, String line) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    int count = 1;
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        result.add(matcher.group(count++));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks a bunch, i ll try it out and take it from here. gracias:)

Comment: Some explanations. evaluate() is just a helper function I coded for dealing with regexp. 

With regard to the regex, .*? matches any character but the shortest matching possible. If you skip the '?' character, '.*' will match all the characters of the string. Enclosing a regex in parenthesis makes the matched pattern available to be retrieved later. Since you're only interested in the landing_url, that's the pattern that is enclosed in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this in java.

I guess the right answer depends on:

1. how robust of a parsing mechanism you need
2. how unique the href value string is, and
3. whether or not you already have an HTML parser in place.

Assuming you've got an HTML parser in place and you can actually grab the href attribute value for the  tag, the easiest way to grab the landing_url from the string is to use methods of the String class. While these methods provide a quick and dirty solution, they may not be robust enough for all the permutations of your string.

Here is some pseudo-code to consider, it's not going to be super efficient or robust, but it would get the job done.

```
(assuming the value is in String hrefValue)
int x = hrefValue.indexOf("landing_url");
int substringStart = "landing_url=".length();
String substring = hrefValue.substring(substringStart);
```

Comment: i was expecting more like a regex